# LINQ to DropDownList with Server.HtmlDecode

Tags: c#, linq, drop-down-menu, html-encode

I have this code which uses LINQ to populate a DropDownList:

```
var userCategories = DataAccessLayer.Context.Categories
    .Where(c => c.UserName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
    .Select(c => new { c.ID, c.Category })
    .OrderBy(c => c.Category);

CategoryDropDownList.DataSource = userCategories;

CategoryDropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";

CategoryDropDownList.DataTextField = "Category";

CategoryDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Where would I put the Server.HtmlDecode for Category?

Comment: what makes you think you need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want HtmlEncode, not HtmlDecode.  Here's an example:

```
foreach (var category in userCategories)
{
    CategoryDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Server.HtmlEncode(category.Category), category.ID.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Your code worked great, thanks for that.  However I do need to do HtmlDecode as I encoded it into the database and now I'm decoding it to show the user the items in the DropDownList.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems backwards.  You shouldn't need to encode it to store in your database.  Encoding is for displaying... not for storing.